# How to handle Set(LinkedHashSet) using play's Form.form helper?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework-2.0, jpa-2.0

I have the following scenario

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children = new LinkedHashSet<Child>();
   }
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Whenever I try to parse JSON to a play's Form using **Form.form(Parent.class).bindFromRequest()** I get the following exception

```
Execution exception[[InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'children[0]' of bean class [models.Parent]: Illegal attempt to get property 'child' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'children[0]' of bean class [models.Parent]: Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path 'children[0]']]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) [scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'children[0]' of bean class [models.Parent]: Illegal attempt to get property 'children' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'children[0]' of bean class [models.Parent]: Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path 'children[0]'
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:848) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:571) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:548) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:912) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'children[0]' of bean class [models.Parent]: Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path 'children[0]'
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:800) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:571) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:548) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:912) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

I don't want to change the LinkedHashSet to an ArrayList(and change the interface from Set to List) because I have another OneToMany relationship in the same entity(Which would cause **org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException**)...

**What should I do in order to have BeanWrapperImpl handling Sets?**
Is it possible?

EDITED:
*The JSON I'm using is:*

```
{
    "name": "PARENT",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is really appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you also post the JSON / the form data you are trying to consume? And do you really need a LinkedHashSet (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: I have updated and included the JSON structure... I'm using LinkedHashSet in order to avoid Bags...
I'm don't want to use IndexColumn with List to avoid Bags... I prefer using Sets...
I just wondering if it's possible to parse to a Set...
Thanks

Comment: If you are just sending the JSON (let's say you have some API endpoint), you can just use the Json class and don't need any forms. Try this:
    `JsonNode jsonNode = request().body().asJson();
    Logger.debug(jsonNode.toString());
    Parent parent = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, Parent.class);`
In this case you will need to provide at least setters for the `Parent` and `Child` classes.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I was posting in Javascript using .ajax() function.  I had to call JSON.stringify(data) on my json data.